# Solarian Revelations needing Attunement of Specific Type

Tags: starfinder

I bet this is somewhere, but I've checked the books and I can't find it.  I'm looking at most of the revelations that say they do something when the person is attuned or fully attuned.  For example, Dark Matter specifies that it takes a move action to get a small DR bonus.  But it then says that if you're attuned or fully attuned, you don't take the move action and, instead, get a DR equal to half your Solarian level.  I assume they mean attuned in the mode that gives it to you (in this case Graviton).  But I do not see that stipulation anywhere.  Can someone point me to that stipulation if it exists?  If not...does this mean I can be Photon attuned and get the attuned bonus from Dark Matter?